# Problem with XeLaTeX xdv2pdf mode and font compilation

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, linguistics

I recently upgraded to TexLive2013 (Basic) and this broke the setup I use for letters of recommendation. I need to use a legacy university font which requires XeLaTeX in the mode xdv2pdf. MWE is below

```
%!TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX-xdv2pdf
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltxtra} % Loads fontspec, xunicode, metalogo, fxltx2e, and some extra customizations for XeLaTeX
\setmainfont{YaleAdmin}
\begin{document}

 Look at the following data from six different languages and answer the questions below:
\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \textsubscript with arg. spec. 's' on line 25.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \textsuperscript with arg. spec. 's' on line 28.
*************************************************
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty))
kpathsea: Running mktextfm YaleAdmin
/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation Y for YaleAdmin.
/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input YaleAdmin
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf YaleAdmin
! I can't find file `YaleAdmin'.
<*> ...jfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input YaleAdmin

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...jfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input YaleAdmin

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: YaleAdmin.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input YaleAdmin' failed to make YaleAdmin.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "YaleAdmin" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.7 \setmainfont{YaleAdmin}
```

The font is installed in the same directory as other fonts that fontspec can find.

Comment: I should add that the problem does not seem to be with the font name (the solution given as an answer to similar questions).

Comment: I would try to get the document working without xdv2pdf. Beside this: The error message means that the font is not found. Where is it? And are you sure you used the correct name?

Comment: The document compiles fine without this font and without xdv2pdf, and this is the correct font name (it worked before I upgraded the tex installation, and the fonts haven't changed). The font is in ~/Library/fonts.

Comment: Do you mean it finds the font if you don't use xdv2pdf?

Comment: No, it never finds the font; however, with a different font (or system only fonts) it will compile with or without xdv2pdf.

Comment: Here's the reference to a message by Khaled Hosny about `xdv2pdf`: http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2013-March/024120.html Indeed, my TeX Live 2013 *doesn't* have `xdv2pdf` and you're probably using an old version. Not surprising it doesn't work.